# vscode wakatime stuck on initializing

Tags: visual-studio-code, wakatime

I am using wakatime on Vscode, Sublime and Google chrome for about 2 month. Today I found that wakatime stuck on Initializing... (just in vscode).

[image]

Any advise in appriciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall wakatime globally and re-write waka-API. It may work  [image]

Comment: Thanks you.
Sometimes it works but after a while it fails again.